# Android listView adds dynamic views at wrong places

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have custom adapter extending BaseAdapter for a listView. The listview has a LinearLayout to which i am trying to add views dynamically based on a certain condition. Now problem is that, it adds views in wrong rows and some times two views are added at the same time to a single row. Here is the xml for listview adapter layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dynamic_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/groupName_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Group1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/groupContacts_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="a, b , c"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

In my adapter i am trying to add views dynamically to the @id dynamic_layout. Here is my adapter's getView method:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View converView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view;
        TextView group_name;
        LinearLayout dynamic_layout;
        final TextView contacts_names;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;


        // Log.e("size in adapter ", getCount() + " size");
        if (converView == null) {
            converView = this.inflater.inflate(resource, arg2, false);

            group_name = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
            dynamic_layout = (LinearLayout) converView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);
            contacts_names = (TextView) converView
                    .findViewById(R.id.groupContacts);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(group_name, dynamic_layout, contacts_names);
            converView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            //view = converView;

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) converView.getTag();

            group_name = viewHolder.group_name;
            dynamic_layout = viewHolder.layout;
            contacts_names = viewHolder.contacts_names;

        }

        /*
         *  bind the data to the view object
         */
        group_name.setText(g_names.get(position));

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (group_map.get(g_names.get(position)).size() == 1) {
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.one_item_view, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.group_tv);
            textView.setText("one Item");

            ((LinearLayout) dynamic_layout).addView(v);


        }else if (group_map.get(g_names.get(position)).size() == 2) {
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.two_items_view, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.two_group_tv1);
            textView.setText("left Item ");

            TextView textView2 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.two_group_tv2);
            textView2.setText("right Item ");

            ((LinearLayout) dynamic_layout).addView(v);


        }

        return converView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rows from your `listview` become visible, system will call `getView`. First time `converView` will be `null`. You need to create a new view and return it back. Once you do that, next time `getView` will be called with the previous view you returned. Because you have no changes in your rows, it is safe to return same view back.

In your original code, you don't have everything inside `if (converView == null) {...}`, so you were unnecessarly creating new views and adding them using `((LinearLayout) dynamic_layout).addView(v);` each time.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View converView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    if (converView == null) {
        converView = this.inflater.inflate(resource, arg2, false);

        TextView group_name = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
        LinearLayout dynamic_layout = (LinearLayout) converView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);
        TextView contacts_names = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.groupContacts);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(group_name, dynamic_layout, contacts_names);
        converView.setTag(viewHolder);

        // bind the data to the view object
        group_name.setText(g_names.get(position));

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (group_map.get(g_names.get(position)).size() == 1) {
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.one_item_view, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.group_tv);
            textView.setText("one Item");

            ((LinearLayout) dynamic_layout).addView(v);

        } else if (group_map.get(g_names.get(position)).size() == 2) {
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.two_items_view, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.two_group_tv1);
            textView.setText("left Item ");

            TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.two_group_tv2);
            textView2.setText("right Item ");

            ((LinearLayout) dynamic_layout).addView(v);
        }
    }
    return converView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Caner. Works like a charm. would you mind explaining this issue. what was wrong with my version ?

Comment: @sayed.jalil Added explanation to my answer, please have a look.